# Discrepancy between db.stats()/collections number & db.getCollectionNames() count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I am playing around in the `mongodb-shell` trying to learn about `mongodb`, and noticed that `db.stats()` shows number of collections to be 1 more than what is shown by `db.getCollectionNames()`

Here is the example:

```
> db.stats();
{   
  "db" : "learn",
  "collections" : 6,
  "objects" : 47, 
  ...
  ...

  "ok" : 1 
}   

> db.getCollectionNames();
[ "hit_stats", "hits", "system.indexes", "system.profile", "unicorns" ]
```

So `db.stats` says there are **6 collections** where as `db.getCollectionNames` lists only **5 collection names**. Why this discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see this discrepancy because the `system.namespaces` collection which stores collection-information does not include itself. Example with 2 collections (`items` and `user`):

```
> db.system.namespaces.find()
{ "name" : "test.system.indexes" }
{ "name" : "test.items.$_id_" }      // index
{ "name" : "test.items" }
{ "name" : "test.users.$_id_" }      // index
{ "name" : "test.users" }

> db.stats()['collections']
4

> db.getCollectionNames()
[ "items", "system.indexes", "users" ]
```

As you can see `system.namespaces` does not include itself. `db.stats()` does include it in its calculation hence the 1 collection difference. Hope this makes sense.

Also see these bug reports [SERVER-1162](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1162) and [SERVER-1308](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1308).